# Adding click event to iframe

Tags: javascript

I want to add a listener click event to the iframe and try the following methods that don't work.

```
var mainContent = document.getElementById('mainContent');
const doc = mainContent.contentDocument;
doc.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
      console.log(e);
});
```

```
 $('#mainContent').on('load',function(){
        var contents = $(this).contents(); 
        $(contents).find("body").on('click', function(e) {
            console.log(e)
        });
 });
```

```
$($("#mainContent").contents()[0], window).find('body').bind("mouseup", function (e) {
        alert("works");
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can put an invisible "a" tag on top of the iframe or wrap the iframe on a clickable div

Comment: The iframe is wrapped in a clickable div